# PrimeFaces prepend tabView Id to children

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am sure somebody else has this issue but can't find answer anywhere. 
I recently switch from Primefaces 3.0.M2 to 3.0.M4. I have a tabView with id='tabViewId'. This id is prepended to all the DOM children of the tabView thus making all of my ajax requests failed. 
How can I indicate to primefaces not to prependid the parent Id to children id ? Is there a mechanism like prependId="false" it is with form ?

Thanks you all in advance,

Primefaces 3.0.M4
Tomcat 6

Comment: I know you can't prependid="false" but why does your ajax request failing? Can you show us some code?

Answer (score 0):

You can't, just like you can't prependId="false" on datatable.

Comment: My mistake, it was simply that the tab was not loaded because dynamic was set to true. So as the javascript code is under the tab, the function was not recognized. My solution was simply to check if the function exist. Thanks all.